# Debugging kernel panic issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Can I use ftrace to debug kernel panic? As per my understanding it is used for performance issues. Can someone help to clear this doubt?

Comment: Not really, if the kernel panics it cannot do anything except halt... you would not be able to extract the generated trace (assuming one is even generated, which probably is not).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, not really. You may run a trace and output it to the kernel buffer at panic.